# atomikos connections shutdown and autoReconnect doesn't work

Tags: mysql, connection-pooling, connection-timeout, atomikos

my application (runs on a Tomcat server) uses the atomikos connection pool to connect with a mysql database. everything works fine except that the connection will
be shutdown if leave the application server not used for some hours. below is the error message I got when operate the application server again after this happens:

```
:58:28 AM RusticiSoftware.ScormContentPlayer.Util.Logger LogInfo
INFO: Parsing metadata
Aug 15, 2013 9:58:28 AM RusticiSoftware.ScormContentPlayer.DataHelp.JdbcDataHelper ExecuteReturnDbRows
INFO: ExecuteReturnDbRows: failed - The last packet successfully received from the server was 59,735,409     milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 59,735,409 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: The last packet successfully received from the server was 59,735,409 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 59,735,409 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this problem.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3871)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2484)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
at RusticiSoftware.ScormContentPlayer.DataHelp.JdbcDataHelper.ExecuteReturnDbRows(JdbcDataHelper.java:453)
..................................
.................................
.................................

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3852)
... 57 more
```

I do set the autoReconnect to true in my jndi parameters but looks it doesn't work.

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ScormEngineDB" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wgea_scorm?charset=utf8&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;autoReconnect=true"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          username="username" password="password" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection="true" testQuery="select 1"
          maxWait="-1" />
```

I also set the log in the mysql side and find out that the test query (select 1) actually was not sent to mysql because the connection is closed. now I have to restart the application server every morning when the problem happens.

any ideas about this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find out that Tomcat connection pool is used rather than Atomikos connection pool. So Tomcat connection pool parameters should be used in the JNDI configuration. It should be like:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/ScormEngineDB" auth="Container"
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wgea_scorm?charset=utf8&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;autoReconnect=true"
          factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
          username="username" password="password" maxActive="20" maxIdle="10" autoReconnectForConnectionPools="true"   
autoReconnectForPools="true"   pinGlobalTxToPhysicalConnection="true" 
<!-- below are Tomcat connection pool parameters-->
testOnBorrow="true" logValidationErrors="true" validationQuery="select 1" testWhileIdle="true" 
testOnConnect="true" validationInterval="3000000" maxWait="-1" />
```

the validationInterval parameter can be set to a value that is shorter than the database connection timeout so that the connection can be kept alive.
Regards the autoConnection parameter, many say that it is not recommended so it can be removed from the above JNDI configuration. Refer http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/connection-autoReconnect-td4340944.html for more information